# Why does foreach($array as $value) results in Indeterminate datatype

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

i made the following method, nothing special in here but i get a confusing error:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 FEHLER: konnte Datentyp von Parameter $2 nicht ermitteln (SQL: select * from "roles" where ("name" = Admin) limit 1)
> ```
>
> *("could not determine type of parameter $2")*

It seems like we dont know which datatype $value at Line

```
$role = Role::firstOrNew(array('name' => $value));
```

actually is.

As soon I change it to

```
$role = Role::firstOrNew(array('name' => '$value'));
```

everything is fine. The fact that i used nearly the same procedure few lines above makes me wonder why php does not know the returned datatype.

Maybe someone can explain me the magic behind the scenes :)

```
<?php
namespace App\Modules\AddressManagement\Seeds;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Eloquent, Permission, DB, Voucher, Role, Log;

class DatabaseSeeder extends \Illuminate\Database\Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();
        // Add Permissions
        $permissions = [
            'am_read_global_address' => ['Bundesweit Adressen lesen' => ['Admin', 'Vertriebsleiter']],
            'am_write_global_address' => ['Bundesweit Adressen hinzufügen' => ['Admin', 'Vertriebsleiter']],
            'am_read_region_address' => ['Regional Adressen lesen' => ['Regionalleiter']],
            'am_write_region_address' => ['Regional Adressen schreiben' => ['Regionalleiter']],
            'am_read_branches_address' => ['Branchnweit Adressen lesen' => ['Branchenmanager']],
            'am_write_branches_address' => ['Branchenweit Adressen schreiben' => ['Branchenmanager']]
        ];


        // Deploy permission to database
        // Update if permission already exists
        foreach ($permissions as $pname => $roles) {
            $permission = Permission::firstOrNew(array('name' => $pname));
            $permission->display_name = key($roles);
            $permission->save();

            foreach ($roles as $value) {
                $role = Role::firstOrNew(array('name' => $value)); // Without enclosed ' we get indeterminate datatype, php PLS 
                $role->save();
                $role->perms()->attach($permission->id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Like the answer below $value is actually an array. This wasnt intended. I had an array_pop in my solution before i posted it in here but for some reasons i deleted it and got that error. Didn't thought about that. The complete code is here (and it works, so everything is fine!). The fact that single quotes makes variables to pure strings was new for me, so ty for that.

```
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();
    // Add Permissions
    $permissions = [
        'am_read_global_address' => ['Bundesweit Adressen lesen' => ['Admin', 'Vertriebsleiter']],
        'am_write_global_address' => ['Bundesweit Adressen hinzufügen' => ['Admin', 'Vertriebsleiter']],
        'am_read_region_address' => ['Regional Adressen lesen' => ['Regionalleiter']],
        'am_write_region_address' => ['Regional Adressen schreiben' => ['Regionalleiter']],
        'am_read_branches_address' => ['Branchnweit Adressen lesen' => ['Branchenmanager']],
        'am_write_branches_address' => ['Branchenweit Adressen schreiben' => ['Branchenmanager']]
    ];


    // Deploy permission to database
    // Update if permission already exists
    foreach ($permissions as $pname => $perm) {
        $permission = Permission::firstOrNew(array('name' => $pname));
        $permission->display_name = key($perm);
        $permission->save();
        $roles = array_pop($perm);

        foreach ($roles as $value) {
            $role = Role::firstOrCreate(array('name' => $value));
            try {
                $role->perms()->attach($permission->id);
            } catch(\Exception $e) {
                // Nothing but duplicate entry, ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more the ORM's "fault" rather that PHP related stuff.

Comment: This is more my fault than any others :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `Role::firstOrNew` is expecting a differently structured first argument and complaining that it cannot deal with whatever you're passing it (I can find several examples online, but no actual Laravel documentation to support this claim). The value associated with the `name` key in the argument you gave should most likely be a string. When you do this:

```
'$value'
```

You end up with a string because single quoted strings in PHP do not attempt to translate variables. Since the value of `key($roles)` will always be a string in your example, and `$value` is an array, I find it likely that the value associated with the `name` key should be a string instead of an array. Maybe something like this?

```
 $role = Role::firstOrNew(array('name' => $value[0]));
```

Comment: Holy moly, i suck :DD... I forgot that i've had add an array_pop before i iterated through the roles, but for some reasons i removed it... Magic explained, ty sir.

Comment: np..disapearing lines plauge us all